# Can I give jsoup a fallback character encoding to use when meta tags aren't found?

Tags: html, character-encoding, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to parse HTML files which have unknown character encodings.  I am calling `Jsoup.parse` with a null charset and lettting Jsoup autodetect.  Some of the files have `meta` tags and Jsoup picks that up nicely.

Some of my files however have no `meta` tags and use various encodings that are not `UTF-8`.  Jsoup falls back to `UTF-8` for these cases resulting in some broken characters.

I have found that the [juniversalchardet](https://code.google.com/archive/p/juniversalchardet/) library is able to autodetect these cases correctly.  For example it correctly detected the `WINDOWS-1252` encoding in several examples.

---

Ideally I want to use the `meta` tags if they exist.  If they do not then fallback to what juniversalchardet reports (not just guess `UTF-8`).

1. Can I provide Jsoup with a fallback charset to use only in cases when it cannot find a meta tag?
2. Alternatively, can I get info from Jsoup about whether it had to guess the encoding or not?  If it reports that it guessed then I could call out to juniversalchardet and then reparse with an explicit encoding passed to Jsoup.

---

I have looked into the source code of Jsoup and as of v1.8.3 it appears that the code to detect the charset from `meta` tags is not factored out into a separate method (look for source of `org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil` class).  Additionally information about whether it guessed or not does not appear to make it to the resulting document.

Is there a better way to achieve my goal?  Is there a library for detecting character encodings of files that already can make use of html meta tags if they exist, which I could use inplace of jsoup's auto-detetion entirely?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/).  It has an `HtmlEncodingDetector` class to find HTML `meta` tags.  When that fails due to meta tags not existing I fallback to Tika's `UniversalEncodingDetector`.  (The latter is a wrapper for juniversalchardet.  I use the wrapper instead of calling juniversalchardet directly because it's handy for both detectors to have the same Java interface.)

I effectively never use Jsoup's auto detection now.

The only caveat is that Tika is quite a large project and adding it pulled in a large number of irrelevant dependencies.